# Using .htaccess to make subdirectory act like subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

It's a little difficult for me to ask the question correctly in title, but mainly here's what I'm trying to figure out.

If I use .htaccess on my website and say I'm trying to create a specific path "redirect" so that anything inside that path uses it's non-redirected path for it's relative path. Sorry for the structure of that sentence.

So for example...

I have my website as-

```
http://www.example.com/
```

I want to keep things organized so I create a sub-folder/subdirectory to keep all these folders inside of.

```
http://www.example.com/projects/
```

So the folder *projects* will be the place holder for all future projects and I want to create a folder inside *projects* for each project, so that I can define a URL for each one like such...

```
http://www.example.com/SuperFish/
http://www.example.com/AquaFear/
```

Now the folder for *SuperFish* and *AquaFear* would be under `http://www.example.com/projects/` but also in their own folder say...

```
http://www.example.com/projects/01/
http://www.example.com/projects/02/
```

Now it'd be fine and dandy to keep the links like such, but for memory purposes and to share with other people the links to those projects, I'd like to just create a nice simpler URL with a custom *"name"*. like `http://www.example.com/SuperFish/` instead of `http://www.example.com/projects/01/`.

Now I was able to do this partially with my .htaccess file in the root folder with this code...

---

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteRule    ^SuperFish/?$    projects/01/    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^AquaFear/?$     projects/02/    [NC,L]
```

---

The issue with this though is that now I can't use relative paths with my *SuperFish* or *AquaFear* made up URL links. Anything such as .css, .js, .etc... Isn't within scope because it's trying to look for those files through the made up URL rather than the real physical one.

So the question is, how would I make it so that I can use my made up URL and also have the webpage load things to the real physical path or somehow fix the relative paths by doing this within the .htaccess file?

The reason I titled this the way it is, is due to subdomains being able to find their files with relative paths even though they're a subdirectory just the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using final $ blocks files inside this two folders from being redirect correctly. You could tried instead :

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteRule    ^SuperFish/?(.*)$    projects/01/$1    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^AquaFear/?(.*)$     projects/02/$1    [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That was exactly it! :)

I've been searching for hours to read up on .htaccess and it's all really presented in a way that makes the information harder to understand for me at atleast. Thank you so much!